# MIPS, using a while loop to calculatethe sum of odd integers 1-9

Tags: mips

The following is my code in MIPS to calculate the sum of odd integers using a while loop.

```
.data
    num: .space 4


.text
.globl main
main:
    li $t1, 1
    li $t2, 9   # make $t2 9 to break the loop
    li $t3, 1   

loop:
        beq     $t3, 11, Exit   # check to see if $t3 = 11 if so exit
        addi    $t3, $t3, 2 # change $t3 to next odd number by adding 2   
        add $t1, $t1, $t3   # add $t3 to $t1 (1+3,...3+5...etc...)

    j loop  #jump back to the start of the loop
Exit:
        li $v0, 1   # system call code to print an int
        lw $a0, num # address of int to print
        syscall     # print the int
    jr $ra  #exit
```

This is my first real experience with MIPS and I'm not sure what is going wrong in this code. I put the print inside the while loop to see if it was ever calculating, but the result is always 1.
So, my result at the end is just 111111.

Edit: Removed the prints inside of the loop with the same result.

And OS is Windows 7 64x

Update: Having num as a variable was over complicating things. Code has been revised as follow and works. Thank you for the help!

```
enter code here
.data   
.text
.globl main
main:
    addi $t1, $0, 1
    addi $t2, $0, 3 

loop:   bge     $t2, 11, Exit   # check to see if $t3 >= 11 if so exit
        add $t1, $t1, $t2   # add $t2 to $t1 (1+3,...3+5...etc...)    
        addi    $t2, $t2, 2 # change $t2 to next odd number by adding 2

    j loop  #jump back to the start of the loop
Exit:
        li $v0, 1   # system call code to print an int
        move $a0,$t1    # address of int to print
        syscall     # print the int

    jr $ra  #exit
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Is its behaviour changed if you remove the print from within the loop?

Comment: You're printing the value stored at `num`, but I don't see you ever writing anything to `num`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
la $t1, num
```

You're clearly getting into trouble here, since you're overwriting your accumulator with the address of `num` every time you're making the syscall. You're losing the current state of your calculation each time.

You'll need to either save your registers, or simply use different ones. Since I don't know what OS it is that you're using, I don't know if you more generally need to save registers over a syscall, but that could also be a source of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar problems for an architecture class and this seemed to be a recurrent problem among all students. When facing problems similar to this our professor's recommendation was to use a different register to temporarily store the register's address to avoid overwriting other desired values from our most commonly used regs.